# Apply a function with two fields of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe like this (To create a sample dataframe);

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'language': ['ruby','ruby','ruby', np.nan,'ruby'],
                   'top_lang_owned': [['ruby', 'javascript', 'go'], 
                                      ['ruby', 'coffeescript'],
                                      ['javascript', 'coffeescript'],
                                      ['ruby', 'shell', 'go'],
                                      np.nan],
                   'top_lang_watched': [['ruby','go'], 
                                      ['javascript'],
                                      np.NaN,
                                      ['ruby', 'shell'],
                                      np.nan]})
df
```

> ```
>   language    top_lang_owned          top_lang_watched
> 0 ruby     [ruby, javascript, go]     [ruby, go]
> 1 ruby     [ruby, coffeescript]       [javascript]
> 2 ruby     [javascript, coffeescript]  NaN
> 3 NaN      [ruby, shell, go]          [ruby, shell]
> 4 ruby      NaN                        NaN
> ```

```
dataframe.info();
```

> ```
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
> Data columns (total 2 columns):
> language          4 non-null object
> top_lang_owned    4 non-null object
> dtypes: object(2)
> memory usage: 208.0+ bytes
> ```

I want to add a field that comparing two fields' values. (pseudo-code)

```
if ("language" is in "top_lang_owned") 
then new_field = 1 othervise new_field = 0.
```

For example, the desired output is must be below;

> ```
> language  top_lang_owned           top_lang_watched  is_owned is_watched
> 0 ruby    [ruby, javascript, go]      [ruby, go]       1       1
> 1 ruby    [ruby, coffeescript]        [javascript]     1       0
> 2 ruby    [javascript, coffeescript]   NaN             0       0
> 3 NaN     [ruby, shell, go]           [ruby, shell]    NaN     NaN
> 4 ruby     NaN                         NaN             NaN     NaN
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do that,
Here's the code you might want to try,

**EDIT:**

```
def func(x):
    if x.language in x.top_lang_owned:
        return 1
    return 0

df['is_in_lang'] = df[~df.isna().any(1)].apply(func, axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    id language                    top_lang_owned  is_in_lang
0   21     ruby            [ruby, javascript, go]           1
1   25     ruby  [javascript, ruby, coffeescript]           1
2   38     ruby        [javascript, coffeescript]           0
3  108      NaN                 [ruby, shell, go]           NaN
4  173     ruby                               NaN           NaN
```

Comment: types of both of fields are "object", I guess, this code can run for string/list fields.

Comment: `dataframe['language'] = dataframe['language'].astype(str)` but it still object

Comment: Oh! my mistake.

Comment: @babeyh Updated the answer, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: ValueError: ('The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: I think, I must convert to string (language), then convert object to list (top_lang) but I can't handle this.

Comment: @babeyh that's weird i've tried to run the updated code in my machine and it successfully produces the output??

Comment: could you try my sample dataframe?

Comment: @babeyh sure give me some time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208509/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-babeyh).

Comment: `df['is_in_lang'] = df[~df[['language','top_lang_owned']].isna().any(1)].apply(func, axis=1)` if edit, it works with all columns. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter NA and apply the condition:

```
df['is_in_lang'] = df[~df.isna().any(1)].apply(lambda x: 1 if x['language'] in x['top_lang_owned'] else 0, 1)

  language                    top_lang_owned  is_in_lang
0     ruby            [ruby, javascript, go]         1.0
1     ruby  [javascript, ruby, coffeescript]         1.0
2     ruby        [javascript, coffeescript]         0.0
3      NaN                 [ruby, shell, go]         NaN
4     ruby                               NaN         NaN
```